# Firebase child security rules with dynamic paths

Tags: json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

assuming I have a firebase json structure like this:

```
    "lgbxwerta":  {
        "xlakshjjsjjh" {
            "message_sender":"+23481772233",
            "message":"Hello"
        },

        "lkhshyujshhsjj" {
            "message_sender":"+234813237263",
            "message":"Hi"
        }
    }
```

Now these are two messages sent by two different users (authenticated by their phone numbers) to a room, and that room has an id that is the same as the user id of one of the participants in the room. 
How do I set rules to allow a user read or write only into a room that id is equivalent to his/her own user id(user id is unique and dynamic).

That is if a room id == "lgbxwerta", then any user with a user id that is the same as the room id can read or write to that room. Any ideas? Believe me, I just couldn't figure this out when I read this documentation- https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data

Comment: Can you explain what do you mean by `user id is unique and dynamic`? How can it be both at the same time? - would a user have 2 or more id's during his lifetime? because `auth.uid` for example, isn't dynamic, and you can use it.

Comment: sorry, mistake. The user id is unique. Please ignore the 'dynamic' part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use wildcards for that. Which are like variables that represents that there will be a dynamic data there at the run time.

```
  "$room_id":
      {
         //if user logged in allow read and write to him only if his uid is same with the $room_id
         ".read": "auth != null && $room_id === auth.uid",
         ".write": "auth != null && $room_id === auth.uid"
      }
```

Comment: @EbubeEmeka You're welcome. If this is solved your problem could you click to tick icon at left side of my answer.